# Live search in a select bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

Hello I have a select in bootstrap 5 with this code

```
                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                       <select  class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"  [(ngModel)]="selectedVariable" (change)="capture()" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" style="width:91%;" >
                            <option value="0">Select..</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.id}} : {{user.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Is there any way to make that select allow a live search?

I saw a similar question that recommended using datalist, I tried it and it was not viable for the solution because of the way the information is displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: https://select2.org/searching

Comment: You can use bootstrap-select jquery - https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search